# Верстка писем, фоновое изображение

Tags: html, css, outlook, вёрстка-email

В таблице в теге `<td>` я прописываю `background="https://name.com/static/name/img/bg.`
Как мне сделать чтоб это изображение **растягивалось по ширине и высоте td**? CSS свойство: `backgroundsize: cover` не работает

Comment: background-size?

Comment: поддержка свойств при верстке писем - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для почты такое нельзя делать, там ведь для каждого почтовика свои правила отображения и не все свойства можно использовать, для писем нужно как можно меньше использовать замудреные стили, что бы везде все корректно отображалось.

Вы можете только цветом залить например подложку общую, а тело письма надо делать только с фиксированной шириной и подгонять картинки.